# Updating a Variable doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am running a DAG which attempts to update a Secret. The Secret is stored in the GCP Secret Manager. Code looks like this:

```py
    Variable.set(key=secret_name, value=mapping_list)
```

I get this warning message:

> [2024-02-23 19:45:42.627489+00:00] {variable.py:245} WARNING - The variable my_var is defined in the CloudSecretManagerBackend secrets backend, which takes precedence over reading from the database. The value in the database will be updated, but to read it you have to delete the conflicting variable from CloudSecretManagerBackend

How can I ensure that the new value I set gets propagated to the backend?

---

Ok, so I here's what happened: the first time I ran my code, it tried to call `Variable.set`. The DAG ended successfully, no messages, no warnings, but also: NO NEW Secret in the Secrets backend. So I thought that maybe Airflow couldn't create, for some reason, so I created the Secret manually.

Then when I reran the code, I started getting messages like above. Today I noticed that in the Airflow UI, in the "Variables" page, under Admin, there was a new variable, with the correct name and value. That explains the messages about the conflict! There *was* the same key in the Airflow database as the Secrets backend!

I deleted the variable in the Airflow database, reran my DAG, and I *STILL* get the same warning as above, but now I also get an *error* that causes the DAG to fail when I call `Variable.set`:

> Variable {key} does not exist in the Database and cannot be updated.

So now I really don't know why I'm getting this error: the variable should be cleared from the database and only exist in the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing a case of key collision as explained in the search path [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/secrets-backend/index.html#search-path) of Secret Backend.

Before Airflow updates a Variable value it checks for conflicts (see [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/87b08ad0840a11d8cd5c0b5043d3a341b1a8f258/airflow/models/variable.py#L245-L250)), My recommendation is to avoid cases where the same Variable key is stored both in Airflow DB and in Secret backend. It doesn't make much sense to maintain the two versions of the same key as it raises question of what is the source of truth for the data stored with this key?

Either manage the key as Airflow Variable or as key in Cloud Secret Manager but not in both.
The simple solution is to remove one of them then the error will not be shown any more.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, `Variable.set()` will **always** create the variable in Airflow metasotre. It will not write to secret backend. This is a design choice of Airflow. The reasoning behind it is that secret stores normally don't allow to write keys for users. You need special permissions for writing (Admin etc...)

You encounter the error because you used `Variable.set(key="my_Var", ...)` Airflow checks if the value exist in the secret store (because read access is allowed) and warns you that same key already exist, thus when you will do Variable.get("my_Var") the value from secret store will be returned and the Airflow Variable will be ignored.

I raised https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/37814 to improve the Airflow docs around the `Variable.set()` when working with secret backend.

Comment: Well now I'm confused.... I only use `Variable.get` and `Variable.set` - it's how I access other values in the Secret backend, though this is the first time I've tried to update one. I guess I thought I was _only_ storing values in the the secrets backend. Is there a way to ensure that `Variable.get` and `.set` _only_ go to the secrets backend?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner please see edit to my answer. `Variable.set()` will not write to secret store.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that _not_ writing to the backend was by design. I don't really feel like creating my own writable backend, so I guess I'll have to either stick with a variable that's only in the Airflow database, or come up with something else...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Normally secret stores are not being used with a lot of writes from automated pipelines that run frequently. It's very OK to combine Secret store usage with Airflow variables (but not on the same key).  If you feel this design choice is too harsh feel free to raise discussion with your use case and ideas in the Airflow dev mailing list. We are happy to hear feedback. Rather than implementing your own maybe if your idea to support right is accepted you can implement it directly in the open source.

Comment: Option for a workaround in your case is instead of doing `Variable.set()` you can invoke an operator that updates the key in your secret store. I am not aware that such operator exist in the Google provider but it should be rather simple to write one and use it as a task in your DAG.

Comment: I could use a bash or python operator to call Google's Secret Manager API directly, if I can't make do with just a variable in the database.

Comment: That will work.